# LINQ Method Syntax Basics

Tags: c#, linq

I need just some basic help to get me started. I'm doing an assignment for class, and we have to use LINQ method syntax, and I'm really struggling to get anything to work. All I want in this example is to know how to list the Production.SubCategories for a given Production.Category

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. I just need to get started and I think if I know how to do this I can figure the rest of it out. Online tutorials haven't help me so far...

Comment: Are you using a database management system to store and retrieve this data?

Comment: Its a local db file. AdventureWorks 2014. 

so say I use:

    ProductCategories.Where(s => s.Name == "Components").Select(p 
    => p.ProductSubcategories)

This give me almost everything I want, but too much. Say I just wanted the name of the subcategory, I can't seem to use another where clause for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is select a particular property of the ProductCategories model so you can do this:

`ProductCategories.Select(pg => pg.ProductSubcategories);`

You could also append a `.where` clause if you wanted to narrow it down

Comment: Thank you. I've used this:

    ProductCategories.Where(s => s.Name == "Components").Select(p 
    => 
    p.ProductSubcategories)

to specify which Category of Subcategory, but if I only wanted the name field, what do I do? I've tried another where clause, but no dice.


EDIT: Got it. I did this:

ProductCategories.Where(s => s.Name == "Components").Select(p => p.ProductSubcategories.Select(s => s.Name))

Comment: ProductCategories.Where(s => s.Name == "Components").Select(p => p.ProductSubcategories.Name) ?